# SQL Server Text datatype or Varchar(max) creates databases that are too large

Tags: sql, sql-server, storage, varcharmax

When I use SQL Server `Text` or `Varchar(max)` datatype in a column it creates databases that are too large :  for example 1000 rows in one table containing `varchar(max)` use around 1000 Mb (1Gb) !!!!

Is that normal ?

thanks for help

Edit my text fields are about 5 to 50 kb MAX

Comment: Are you sure it is `varchar` and not `char`?

Comment: It depends on how much is in each record. If each one contains on average 1MB of data, then 1000 of them will make 1GB.

Comment: I think you are asking if 4 explanation points in a row is normal... it is not.  (also, use varchar and not char or text)

Comment: I tried varchar(max) and text.
The text fields are about 4 to 50 ko only.
what's wrong ?

Comment: You may be using a badly written DB library or program, which may be padding your varchar(max) fields with spaces. Check that the data you are inserting is not padded with spaces.

Comment: The DBA site may be a better place for this question.

Comment: @juergen There is not chat(max) data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on what's inside your table.
If you have 1000 rows with 1mb of data, you will have 1000 Mb

Try running:

```
select datalength(yourField) from yourTable
```

the datalength function will give you how many bytes are occupied by the column

Comment: Thanks this really helped me, i am trying to check record by recod to check if really the seize i see is the real seize of data i send

Comment: Check this link for more references: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx
if my answer helepd you, remember to vote and mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

Run sys.sp_spaceused @objname = N'YourTable'; to see the space used by your table.

If there is no unused space, then your data is really taking up that space

If there is a lot of unused space, you could try creating a new filegroup and moving the text/varchar(max) columns to this new file group, and shrinking the database `DBCC SHRINKDB`

After that your primary filegroup will take up less space, and you can shrink the "offending" file using `DBCC SHRINKFILE`, whenever problem arises.

Creating a new filegroup can be done from SSMS, in the database properties, files page. You can generate the sql script from there to see what's going on.

Moving text columns to a different filegroup can be made by using the TEXTIMAGE_ON { filegroup| "default" } in [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174979.aspx)

Sorry: no alter table possible, no individual column to different filegroup, but all "big" columns at once. So you have to do it by hand or show your table in a new database diagram (in SSMS studio) and change the property ... sorry I don't know it's name, something like "Text/Image filegroup" (I suppose, I've got Spanish SSMS), but it's there when you see the table properties in the database diagram designer.

Advantages: less fragmentation on the main table, faster table/clustered index sacans and possiblity to shrink only the file you're interested in: the with the problematic "big" columns.

Comment: Yes the table is taking up that place.
What do you mean by filegroup ? Can you explain what to do ? 

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

varchar(max) is different with varchr(n);

a varchar(max) cell can contain 2 GByte data.

but for varchar(n):  the max number of n is 8000, means max 8 KByte data.

but, any way, I don't know what kind of data you stored in your database.

so,in short,  **possibly normal**.

Comment: look at his comment: texts of 4 to 50kb in each row... that shouldn't add up to 1Gb.

Comment: @JotaBe that's weird. if 50KB in each row, 1000 row should be 50MB. so    maybe some rows have bigger data